# Ordering Menu Items in TideSDK

Tags: python, titanium, tidesdk

I'm adding main menu items to my application. But, they get added only after the default 'Edit' menu item.

```
new_menu = Ti.UI.createMenu()
fileItem = new_menu.addItem('File')
settingsItem = new_menu.addItem('Settings')

Ti.UI.setMenu(new_menu)
```

This is the result:
[image]

Obviously, I want 'File' to come before Edit. I'd like to remove 'Edit' and 'Window' if possible. How do I do this?

Comment: I have the same question, and haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is an open issue:
https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues/112